# How can i interchange widget's displaying data through other connected flutter apps

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am building a card game in which the card stack depends on 4 flutter friend apps which will be displayed on the screen. I know this is not a very technical question but still is for me i am learning this thing. I have searched all over the internet cannot find the solution, Just give me anything and I'll study and apply that.

Comment: Please add a little more information so we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, but maybe [Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I) will help?
It allows you to synchronize your app's data between different devices on internet.

Comment: Actually iam trying to make a card game the picture would be the card which a friend flutter app will select.